# Is it possible to get highlighted html content from user?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick, dom-events

When I use onClick in reactjs I get the whole property like

Lorem Ipsum **is simply dummy** text

. But I need only the only highlighted content such as "***is simply dummy***". How it is possible?

Comment: <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet to get the selection

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  function getSelectedText() {
    let selectedText = window.getSelection().toString()
    setText(selectedText);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>this is a piece of text that can be seleted partially</p>
      <button onMouseDown={getSelectedText}>select</button>
      <h3>{text}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey sathya reddy,
It's working. But when any user clicks or highlights from iframe it is not working. Do you know how is it possible?

Comment: It might be possible but that would be very difficult task to achieve because iFames are totally separate documents from your document.